# Ubuntu - .desktop file linked to Python script - script works but logging doesn't

Tags: python, logging

I have a Python script placed in the `Exec` of `Start.desktop` as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=Start
Exec=/home/user/Desktop/script.py
Comment=startup
```

Double-clicking the icon brings up my GUI and the Terminal with the script's output and all is well.

But unfortunately the script **does not** add to the existing log file `script.log`!

When I run my script from the command line `python script.py` the script **does** add to the log file. I am very confused here!

I have my logging setup to print to the Terminal and the log file as follows:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-5.5s] % 
        (message)s",
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler('script.log'),
        logging.StreamHandler()
    ], level=logging.DEBUG, datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
)
```

In my attempts I tried creating a wrapper `wrapper.sh` with the following:

```
#!usr/bin/env bash
script.py > script.log
```

...and then placed `wrapper.sh` in the `Exec` section of `Start.desktop`. No luck there; running this setup erased my log file completely and added no new entries.

For what it's worth I made sure permissions were OK using `chmod +x` and `chmod +r` on `Start.desktop` and `script.py` (not sure if that matters here). All the output from the file is `logging.debug('stuff')` lines.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I couldn't find much so I double-checked all my paths and such.

I tried providing a full path to the log file inside `script.py` such that:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-5.5s] % 
        (message)s",
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler('/home/user/Desktop/script.log'),
        logging.StreamHandler()
    ], level=logging.DEBUG, datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
)
```

and with that my issue was resolved.

Must be due to the .desktop file not having a reference for any sort of current directory, whereas running `script.py` from the same directory as the `script.log` is fine because they are in the same directory.